# Cortana RequestDisambiguationAsync Error

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get user interaction with a background app through Cortana working for my app.

Whenever I do RequestDisambiguationAsync(response) Cortana just says that it ran into an error. However, it isn't breaking anywhere in Visual Studio.

Any ideas on what may be causing it? Below is the code that I am using:

```
var userPrompt = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
string home1 = data.Structures[0].Name;
string home2 = data.Structures[1].Name;
userPrompt.DisplayMessage = "Which one did you want to set to home?";
userPrompt.SpokenMessage = String.Format("Which one did you want to set to home? {0} or {1}?", home1, home2);

var userReprompt = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
userReprompt.DisplayMessage = "Which one did you want to set to home?";
userReprompt.SpokenMessage = "Which one did you want to set to home?";

var structuresContentTiles = new List<VoiceCommandContentTile>();

var structureTile = new VoiceCommandContentTile();
structureTile.ContentTileType = VoiceCommandContentTileType.TitleWith68x68IconAndText;
structureTile.Title = home1;
structureTile.AppContext = data.Structures[0].Structure_id;
structuresContentTiles.Add(structureTile);

var structureTile2 = new VoiceCommandContentTile();
structureTile2.ContentTileType = VoiceCommandContentTileType.TitleWith68x68IconAndText;
structureTile2.Title = home2;
structureTile.AppContext = data.Structures[1].Structure_id;
structuresContentTiles.Add(structureTile2);

var response = VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponseForPrompt(userPrompt, userReprompt, structuresContentTiles);

var voiceCommandDisambiguationResult = await voiceServiceConnection.RequestDisambiguationAsync(response);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior can occur in some cases when you use

```
structureTile.ContentTileType = VoiceCommandContentTileType.TitleWith68x68IconAndText;
```

but do not supply an image. Change it to VoiceCommandContentTileType.TitleOnly, or if you're supplying a Line1, use VoiceCommandContentTileType.TitleWithText, or provide an Image, and that should stop the failure from occurring.